# How to convert DBX files to PST

Tags: microsoft-outlook, conversion, pst

I'm trying to find a program to convert DBX files to the PST format, but i'm only finding paid programs.

Answer (score 3):

Why not import the files in Outlook Express, and then Import from Outlook Express to Outlook ?

Comment: You're rght, did not look quite well..

Comment: Yes, isn't outlook expresses native inbox format dbx?

Answer (score 1):

A trial: [DBX Converter](http://www.dbxconverter.com/)
Another trial: [Extract DBX](http://www.convertdbxtopst.com/)

I guess there is no really free stuff for this. You might want to check the Microsoft Forums, you might get your answer there?

[Microsoft Forums](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/forums/default.mspx)